# c# Reverse proxy not returning response from 1 internal service

Tags: c#, postman

I have a c# reverse proxy. It is working for one internal service (A), but there is one that is failing (B). 
I am using Postman to test. 
Connecting to (A) shows the following in the Reverse proxy logs.

```
DEBUG - Internal server responded with 22119
DEBUG - Internal server responded 
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
....
```

Connecting to (B) shows the following in the Reverse proxy logs.

```
DEBUG - Internal server responded with 4478
DEBUG - Internal server responded 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<!-- Login page -->
<HTML>
```

The essential lines are included below

```
byte[] responseData = server.GetResponseStreamBytes(internalResponse);
Log.Debug("Internal server responded with " + responseData.Length.ToString());
Log.Debug("Internal server responded \n" +
                      System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseData));

for (int i = 0; i < internalResponse.Headers.Count; ++i)
{
   externalResponse.AddHeader(internalResponse.Headers.Keys[i], internalResponse.Headers[i]);
}
externalResponse.OutputStream.Write(responseData, 0, responseData.Length);
externalResponse.End();
```

By debugging, it is the line

```
externalResponse.End();
```

that causes Postman to report "Could not get any response", the write statement executes correctly.
Both A and B services work properly if connected to directly with a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Internal service was returning a chunked response. Transferring all headers back to the client caused an ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING that was only apparent through Chrome, not postman. Resolved by removing the "Transfer-Encoding" header.